# How to access id passed in Route inside Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I have this Route Configured.

```
<Router history={history}>
      <div>
         <NavBar />
     <Route path='/home' exact strict component={HomePageContainer} />
     <Route  path='/edit/:id' component={EditSchool}  />
       </div>
        </Router>
```

i want to access the value of the id which is dynamically passed to component EditSchool.
This is my Link Tag

```
 <Link to={'edit/'+schools.id }> {schools.school_name}</Link>
```

This is what my URL looks like:

```
/edit/12
```

But how do I access the value 12, inside the component?

```
this.props.route
```

returns undefined.

Should I pass a prop to the route and then access it?

Please, someone, Help.

Comment: `console.log(this.props)`. What do you see?

Comment: yeah found it. i am getting the json data.

Comment: @FrankerZ this.props.match.params.id is what i needed to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with `this.props.match.params.id`.

Comment: yes its working now ,  thank you Alex :)